# SAX XML File Parsing (JAVA)

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax, invoice

I have to create a class to extract data from an xml named invoice.xml which I created. In the xml, a customer may buy more than one item. The problem upon printing the extracted data is that if that is the case, only the last element purchased by a customer will be printed. 
Could anyone suggest a solution? I will also attach my xml file because I'm pretty sure that's where the problem lies.

SAXParserExample.java

```
package Attempt2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class SAXParserExample extends DefaultHandler {

    List<Invoice> myInvoices;
    private String tempVal;
    private Invoice tempInv;

    public SAXParserExample() {
        myInvoices = new ArrayList<Invoice>();
    }

    public void runExample() {
        parseDocument();
        printData();
    }

    private void parseDocument() {
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            sp.parse("invoice.xml", this);

        } catch (SAXException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void printData() {
        System.out.println("\n\n\tNo of Invoices '" + myInvoices.size()
                + "'.\n");
        Iterator<Invoice> it = myInvoices.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("\n\t" + it.next().toString());
        }
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        tempVal = "";
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Invoice")) {
            tempInv = new Invoice();
        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        tempVal = new String(ch, start, length);
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("invoice")) {
            myInvoices.add(tempInv);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("invoicenum")) {
            tempInv.setInvoiceNum(tempVal);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
            tempInv.setTitle((tempVal));
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            tempInv.setName((tempVal));
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("street")) {
            tempInv.setStreet((tempVal));
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("city")) {
            tempInv.setCity((tempVal));
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("county")) {
            tempInv.setCounty((tempVal));
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("postal")) {
            tempInv.setPostal((tempVal));
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
            tempInv.setDescription((tempVal));
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("price")) {
            tempInv.setPrice((tempVal));
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("quantity")) {
            tempInv.setQuantity((tempVal));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SAXParserExample spe = new SAXParserExample();
        spe.runExample();
    }

}
```

invoice.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE people SYSTEM "invoice.dtd">
<invoices> 
    <invoice>
        <invoicenum>Invoice# 12345</invoicenum>
        <address>
            <title>Customer Address</title>
            <name>William Owen</name>
            <street>99 Anywhere Avenue</street>
            <city>Bangor</city>
            <county>Gwynedd</county>
            <postal>LL57 3JP</postal>
        </address>
        <items>
            <order>Items Ordered</order>
            <item>
                <description>Ink Jet Refill Kit</description>
                <price>29.50</price>
                <quantity>2</quantity>
            </item>
            <item>
                <description>4-Port Mini Hub</description>
                <price>19.95</price>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </item>
        </items>
    </invoice>
    <invoice>
        <invoicenum>Invoice# 12346</invoicenum>
        <address>
            <title>Customer Address</title>
            <name>Alex Gavra</name>
            <street>14 Menai View Terrace</street>
            <city>Bangor</city>
            <county>Gwynedd</county>
            <postal>LL57 2HF</postal>
        </address>
        <items>
            <order>Items Ordered</order>
            <item>
                <description>200GB External Disk Drive</description>
                <price>83.50</price>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </item>
        </items>
    </invoice>
    <invoice>
        <invoicenum>Invoice# 12347</invoicenum>
        <address>
            <title>Customer Address</title>
            <name>Mark Reeves</name>
            <street>Neuadd Llys Trifan</street>
            <city>Bangor</city>
            <county>Gwynedd</county>
            <postal>LL57 2JS</postal>
        </address>
        <items>
            <order>Items Ordered</order>
            <item>
                <description>19 Inch LCD Monitor LG</description>
                <price>120</price>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </item>
            <item>
                <description>Wireless mouse Laser Microsoft</description>
                <price>17.55</price>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </item>
        </items>
    </invoice>
    <invoice>
        <invoicenum>Invoice# 12348</invoicenum>
        <address>
            <title>Customer Address</title>
            <name>Nick Murray</name>
            <street>10 Some Street</street>
            <city>London</city>
            <county>London</county>
            <postal>WC1</postal>
        </address>
        <items>
            <order>Items Ordered</order>
            <item>
                <description>Microsoft keyboard SF200</description>
                <price>60.50</price>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </item>
            <item>
                <description>Screen cleaner spray</description>
                <price>4.59</price>
                <quantity>3</quantity>
            </item>
            <item>
                <description>Office chair</description>
                <price>149.99</price>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </item>
        </items>
    </invoice>
    <invoice>
        <invoicenum>Invoice# 12349</invoicenum>
        <address>
            <title>Customer Address</title>
            <name>Michael Jones</name>
            <street>Somewhere Street 18</street>
            <city>London</city>
            <county>London</county>
            <postal>E17</postal>
        </address>
        <items>
            <order>Items Ordered</order>
            <item>
                <description>PLX Elastic Bands</description>
                <price>15.73</price>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </item>
        </items>
    </invoice>
</invoices>
```

Also, after having created my java class, I get the following message in my xml document where more than one item is inserted:

[image]

I have little knowledge af DTD's but here's what I've got written:

invoice.dtd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT invoices (invoice*)>
<!ELEMENT invoice (invoicenum, address, items)>
<!ELEMENT address (title, name, street, city, county, postal)>
<!ELEMENT items (order, item)>
<!ELEMENT item (description, price, quantity)>

<!ELEMENT invoicenum (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT street (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT county (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT postal (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT order (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT quantity (#PCDATA)>
```

Also, I'm attaching the Invoice.java class in case there could be a hint to solve this problem.

```
package Attempt2;

public class Invoice {

    private String invoicenum;
    private String title;
    private String name;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String county;
    private String postal;
    private String order;
    private String description;
    private String price;
    private String quantity;

    public Invoice() {
        System.out.println("\n\t No Arg Invoice Constructor Called…");
    }

    public Invoice(String invoicenum, String title, String name, String street,
            String city, String county, String postal, String order,
            String description, String price, String quantity) {
        System.out.println("\n\t 4-Argument Invoice Constructor Called…");
        this.invoicenum = invoicenum;
        this.title = title;
        this.name = name;
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.county = county;
        this.postal = postal;
        this.order = order;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;

    }

    public String getInvoiceNum() {
        return invoicenum;
    }

    public void setInvoiceNum(String invoicenum) {
        this.invoicenum = invoicenum;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // street
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    // city;
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    // county
    public String getCounty() {
        return county;
    }

    public void setCounty(String county) {
        this.county = county;
    }

    // postal
    public String getPostal() {
        return postal;
    }

    public void setPostal(String postal) {
        this.postal = postal;
    }

    // order
    public String getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(String order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    // description
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    // price
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    // quantity
    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    /**
    private String title;
    private String order;
     */
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("Invoice Details \n---------------------------------\n");
        sb.append("Invoice Number:" + getInvoiceNum()+"\n");
        sb.append("Name:" + getName()+"\n");
        sb.append("Street:" + getStreet()+"\n");
        sb.append("City:" + getCity()+"\n");
        sb.append("County:" + getCounty()+"\n");
        sb.append("Postal Code:" + getPostal()+"\n");
        sb.append("Item Description:" + getDescription()+"\n");
        sb.append("Price:" + getPrice()+"\n");
        sb.append("Quantity:" + getQuantity()+"\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to use a framework, like Apache Digester, to read XML files instead homemade code.

Comment: Well it's the requirement of the project that I use Java unfortunately..

Comment: Well, Apache Digester is a Java library.

Comment: No need to use a library here. He already has working code. It would be a waste of time. Plus instead of using a 3rd party library he can just use JAXB instead of a hand built SAX parser. No need to introduce a 3rd party dependency if you don't need to. (JAXB was added to the JDK at about Update 14 of Java 1.6)

Comment: Does your DTD allow multiple items? Personally I find XmlSchemas much easier to read. Can you provide your DTD?

Comment: @Michael I just added my code

Comment: What version of the JDK are you using? I can't get it to fail.

Comment: I have tested with Java 1.5 Update 31 and Java 1.6 Update 26 and it works fine for me in all cases. I am using the Apple VM (mac os) so that may be a difference. Either way, make the changes I specified in my answer and see if that fixes you up.

Answer (score 0):

Since I totally misunderstood your problem and led you astray all day I have fixed your parser so it handles Items as separate objects and now your Invoice contains a List of Items. I apologize!

```
public class Item {
String description;
String price;
String quantity;

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Item");
    sb.append("{description='").append(description).append('\'');
    sb.append(", price='").append(price).append('\'');
    sb.append(", quantity='").append(quantity).append('\'');
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

```
public class Invoice {
String invoiceNum;
String title;
String name;
String street;
String city;
String county;
String postal;
List<Item> items;

public Invoice() {
    this.items = new ArrayList<Item>();
}

public void addItem(Item item) {
    this.items.add(item);
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getCounty() {
    return county;
}

public void setCounty(String county) {
    this.county = county;
}

public String getInvoiceNum() {
    return invoiceNum;
}

public void setInvoiceNum(String invoiceNum) {
    this.invoiceNum = invoiceNum;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPostal() {
    return postal;
}

public void setPostal(String postal) {
    this.postal = postal;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Invoice");
    sb.append("{city='").append(city).append('\'');
    sb.append(", invoiceNum='").append(invoiceNum).append('\'');
    sb.append(", title='").append(title).append('\'');
    sb.append(", name='").append(name).append('\'');
    sb.append(", street='").append(street).append('\'');
    sb.append(", county='").append(county).append('\'');
    sb.append(", postal='").append(postal).append('\'');
    sb.append(", items=").append(items);
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

```
public class SaxParserExample extends DefaultHandler {

List<Invoice> myInvoices;
private String tempVal;
private Invoice tempInv;
private Item tempItem;

public SaxParserExample() {
    myInvoices = new ArrayList<Invoice>();
}

public void runExample() {
    parseDocument();
    printData();
}

private void parseDocument() {
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        sp.parse("invoice.xml", this);

    } catch (SAXException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void printData() {
    System.out.println("No of Invoices '" + myInvoices.size());
    for (Invoice myInvoice : myInvoices) {
        System.out.println(myInvoice);
    }
}

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                         Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    tempVal = "";
    if ("Invoice".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
        tempInv = new Invoice();
    } else if ("item".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
        tempItem = new Item();
    }
}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    tempVal = new String(ch, start, length);
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if ("invoice".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
        myInvoices.add(tempInv);
    } else if ("item".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
        tempInv.addItem(tempItem);
    } else if ("invoicenum".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
        tempInv.setInvoiceNum(tempVal);
    } else if ("title".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
        tempInv.setTitle((tempVal));
    } else if ("name".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
        tempInv.setName((tempVal));
    } else if ("street".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
        tempInv.setStreet((tempVal));
    } else if ("city".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
        tempInv.setCity((tempVal));
    } else if ("county".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
        tempInv.setCounty((tempVal));
    } else if ("postal".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
        tempInv.setPostal((tempVal));
    } else if ("description".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
        tempItem.setDescription((tempVal));
    } else if ("price".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
        tempItem.setPrice((tempVal));
    } else if ("quantity".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
        tempItem.setQuantity((tempVal));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SaxParserExample spe = new SaxParserExample();
    spe.runExample();
}
```

}

Comment: I followed your suggestions but this doesn't fix the problem unfortunately :(

Comment: At least I don't get the error messages in my xml file but I still don't get all items in my list.

Comment: Are there any exceptions thrown? It is finding the invoice.xml file right? Try running the code through your debugger.

Comment: There aren't any exceptions, this is getting really weird now. I have also attached my Invoice class in case something in the formatting is wrong and it just doesn't print the items.

Comment: I tested it with  your Invoice bean and it still works just fine for me.

Comment: So you do get all the item elements in it?

Comment: Yes, I get a List with 5 populated Invoices in it. (using the Invoice class you provided)

Comment: Then why can I not get it? I get the 5 populated invoices too I just can't get the multiple items in whichever invoice they exist. I only get one item description/price/quantity; the last one added in the xml file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9211/discussion-between-michael-and-alex-encore-tr)

Answer (score 0):

the DTD says that one <items> element can only have, one <order> element and one <item> element. In the XML file you have <items> with **two** <item> elements which is wrong with respect the DTD.

If <tems> may have several <item> elements, one solution is to change the following line of the DTD

<!ELEMENT items (order, item)>

to

<!ELEMENT items (order, item+)>

also the following line in the XML file is wrong:

<!DOCTYPE people SYSTEM "invoice.dtd">

it should be

<!DOCTYPE *invoices* SYSTEM "invoice.dtd">

there is no *people* element definition in the DTD